# how to change the ascii character into utf-8 with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, ascii

`A9` stand for  © in ascii table ,how can i  change `A9` in ascii encoding into utf-8 encoding  in python?What is the rule for asii encoding be changed into utf-8?

Comment: "©" is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish, maybe that will help us because the question does not make sense.

Comment: "©" is an extended  ASCII character,its value is a9 ,you can get it in http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/AsciiChart.jsp.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: have you considered that that table might be wrong?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: and there is no standard for [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII); it is a term that carries no reliable meaning. Last but not least, you didn't use the term *extended ASCII*, you talked about just *plain* ASCII. In computer programming, precision is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any given ASCII codepoint **is equal to the UTF-8 encoding** for that codepoint. This is deliberate.

However, `©` is *not an ASCII codepoint*, it is a *Latin-1* codepoint. [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit standard and codepoints run from 00 through to 7F. Beyond that, [Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) runs from U+0080 to U+00FF, requiring 2 UTF-8 bytes per codepoint to encode.

Just decode from Latin 1, encode to UTF-8:

```
>>> b'\xA9'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
b'\xc2\xa9'
```

As for the 'rules' of UTF-8, it's best explained in the [UTF-8 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

For Latin-1 codepoints, whose values fit in a single byte, the rule is simple: the top 2 bits (either `10` or `11`) form the lower two bits of the first byte, together with `110000` as the high bits. The lower 6 bits of the codepoint are given `10` as the high bits.

`A9`, or `10101001` then becomes `11000010 10101001` or `C2 A9`:

```
       10 101001   Latin-1 codepoint A9
       .. ------
       /     \
11000010 10101001  UTF-8 encoding C2 A9
      ..   ------
```

Comment: it is >>> b'\xA9'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8') not >>>  '\xA9'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8') , i have tested it.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: In Python 3, yes, but without you having *specified* that you use Python 3, I had to assume the more common Python 2.